# What is the advantage of using _.toLower from lodash instead of Javascript's toLowerCase()?

Tags: javascript, string, lodash

I am working in a codebase and I see they are using [lodash's `_.toLower` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toLower) instead of [Javascript's built in `.toLowerCase()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) (in addition to a bunch of other lodash utility methods littered throughout the code). I was wondering is there any advantage/reason that lodash provides rather than just using a method that's already built into Javascript?

Comment: `undefined` or `null` doesn't cause any problem in lodash

Comment: Why not ask this question of the people who have worked on the codebase?

Answer (score 2):

The only possible "benefit" (which really isn't much of one IMO) I can see is that `toLower` is also [callable on non-strings](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L14904):

```js
console.log(_.toLower(
  { foo: 'foo' }
));

console.log(_.toLower(
  { toString() { return 'foo' }}
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

(I would prefer to use TypeScript for type-safety in serious codebases and use the built-in `toLowerCase`)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sources, it seems it handles a few edge-cases.
[`_.toLower`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/ddfd9b11a0126db2302cb70ec9973b66baec0975/lodash.js#L14904) calls [`toString()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/ddfd9b11a0126db2302cb70ec9973b66baec0975/lodash.js#L12557) which itself calls [`baseToString()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/ddfd9b11a0126db2302cb70ec9973b66baec0975/lodash.js#L4224). This is where most of the interesting features are implemented.

Below snippet lists these features:

```js
// null & undefined is converted to empty string
test(null);
test(undefined);
// correctly identifies -0
test(-0); // StackSnippet's console also has trouble rendering -0
// Arrays are traversed and baseToString is called recursively
// note that here `null` is converted to `"null"`
test(["AAA", null, -0]); // StackSnippet's console also has trouble rendering -0
// Symbols in Array works fine
test([Symbol("FOO")]); // StackSnippet's console also has trouble rendering this

function test(value) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log("_:", _.toLower(value));
  try {
    console.log("native:", value.toString().toLowerCase());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("native failed");
  }
  console.log("#".repeat(20));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```